# Exported jar file freezes after executing

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Hi I've been having problems trying to export my java code into a runnable jar file.

When I double click the .jar file it starts up but for some reason the only image that I use doesn't show up (since this was a basic test all the objects are draw using shapes from what I think is java.awt). So the only thing that doesn't show up is a bullet sprite in which I put in a data folder next to the src folder.

The main problem is that it seems to crash or freeze after a few seconds of running the game.
(I'm was using eclipse to run it and it worked fine).

Now I'm not that experienced with making this without the compiler so I'm not sure if I had missed anything when making this program

Here is what I have to get the image (which I believe is the main problem):

```
private BufferedImage pShot;
```

//then in the public World method

```
try {
        pShot = ImageIO.read(new File("data/bulletShot2.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: well, help us help you, give some code ;)

Comment: Run it from the command line using java -jar so you have a console on which to see any output.

Comment: I got an error like this javax.image.io.IIOException: Can't read input file! Another error is Exception in thread "AWT-EventQue-0: java.lang.nullPointerException

Comment: how are you reading your file? what path are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by path?

Comment: The path is data/bulletShot2.png it's in a separate source folder than src but in the same project folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
+ src
    + resources
        - bullet.gif 
    + com
        - blah
```

Read your image file like this:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("resources/bullet.gif");
```

You were most likely refering to your file like this:

```
File bullet = new File("./bullet.gif")
```

Which won't work

Comment: I posted what I used to get the image. If I were to use the InputStream would I put that in the constructor method?

Comment: @mkjrfan: check out the ImageIO API, specifically the read method. It accepts a File parameter, yes, but it also has an overload that accepts an InputStream instead. Use epoch's technique to get this InputStream. 1+ to this answer. Deleting my answer for this one as it is more detailed and better.

Comment: Well I tried putting the InputStream in my code but I keep getting an error under the getResourceAsStream() saying it is undefined for the type Thread

Comment: You can also use `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream()` as HoverCraft suggested, sorry i forgot to add you have to get the classloader

Comment: So here is what I tried: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/bulletShot2.png"); and World.class.getResourceAsStream("data/bulletShot2.png"); (World.class is the main class that renders images and where this is being called) both come up as null. I tried putting it as pShot = ImageIO.read(is); but because it is null it wont work.

Comment: where is your data folder?, it should be under `src`

Comment: it goes like this FlightGame: (src) (data: bulletShot2.png)

Comment: put your data folder under src like in the answer

Comment: well i tried just put bulletShot2.png directly into the src itself and still comes up null (which im assuming it can't find it)

Comment: just put the whole data folder there.. or just bullet, and change the code to reference bullet directly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37420/discussion-between-mkjrfan-and-epoch)